# JavaScript code not returning an expected URL as response

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to get [this][1] HTML and JavaScript code to work locally but I am not have success. For example, if you run their code snippet and  choose a language such as "English United States" and click 'Submit" you should being see a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tag in your code is placed above the closing tag of the Form.

```
    <script>
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  const url = new URL("https://api.videoindexer.ai/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index?language=...&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=...");
  const language = document.getElementById("language").value;
  url.searchParams.set("language",language);
  console.log(url); // change to a fetch or similar
})
  </script>
</form>
```

Move the entire script section just above the closing of the body tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
  <select name="language" id="language">
    <option value="en-GB">Please select language (Default en-GB</option> 
    <option value="sr-Cyrl-RS">Serbian (Cyrillic)</option>
    <option value="sr-Latn-RS">Serbian (Latin)</option>
    <option value="bs-Latn">Bosnian</option>
    <option value="zh-Hans">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
    <option value="zh-Hant">Chinese (Traditional)</option>
    <option value="fil-PH">Filipino</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="en-FJ">Fijian</option>
    <option value="en-AU">English Australia</option>
    <option value="en-WS">Samoan</option>
    <option value="en-US">English United States</option>
    <option value="el-GR">Greek</option>
    <option value="es-ES">Spanish</option>
    <option value="et-EE">Estonian</option>
    <option value="fa-IR">Persian</option>
    <option value="fi-FI">Finnish</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">French</option>
    <option value="fr-HT">Haitian</option>
    <option value="af-ZA">Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="ar-SY">Arabic Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="ar-EG">Arabic Egypt</option>
    <option value="da-DK">Danish</option>
    <option value="de-DE">German</option>
    <option value="bg-BG">Bulgarian</option>
    <option value="bn-BD">Bangla</option>
    <option value="mg-MG">Malagasy</option>
    <option value="ms-MY">Malay</option>
    <option value="mt-MT">Maltese</option>
    <option value="ca-ES">Catalan</option>
    <option value="cs-CZ">Czech</option>
    <option value="nl-NL">Dutch</option>
    <option value="nb-NO">Norwegian</option>
    <option value="id-ID">Indonesian</option>
    <option value="it-IT">Italian</option>
    <option value="lt-LT">Lithuanian</option>
    <option value="lv-LV">Latvian</option>
    <option value="ja-JP">Japanese</option>
    <option value="ur-PK">Urdu</option>
    <option value="uk-UA">Ukrainian</option>
    <option value="hi-IN">Hindi</option>
    <option value="he-IL">Hebrew</option>
    <option value="hu-HU">Hungarian</option>
    <option value="hr-HR">Croatian</option>
    <option value="ko-KR">Korean</option>
    <option value="vi-VN">Vietnamese</option>
    <option value="tr-TR">Turkish</option>
    <option value="ta-IN">Tamil</option>
    <option value="th-TH">Thai</option>
    <option value="to-TO">Tongan</option>
    <option value="ru-RU">Russian</option>
    <option value="ro-RO">Romanian</option>
    <option value="pt-BR">Portuguese</option>
    <option value="pl-PL">Polish</option>
    <option value="sv-SE">Swedish</option>
    <option value="sw-KE">Kiswahili</option>
    <option value="sl-SI">Slovenian</option>
    <option value="sk-SK">Slovak</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
      document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
      const url = new URL("https://api.videoindexer.ai/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index?language=...&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=...");
      const language = document.getElementById("language").value;
      url.searchParams.set("language",language);
      console.log(url); // change to a fetch or similar
    })
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since you have the script within the form, The code does not know what to do when it is submitted.

As you want the result below the form and not on the console, you will have to create a DOM element inside the html body and then using the selector change the content of the element, Something like this,

```
   <div>
<form>
  <select name="language" id="language">
    <option value="en-GB">Please select language (Default en-GB</option> 
    <option value="sr-Cyrl-RS">Serbian (Cyrillic)</option>
    <option value="sr-Latn-RS">Serbian (Latin)</option>
    <option value="bs-Latn">Bosnian</option>
    <option value="zh-Hans">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
    <option value="zh-Hant">Chinese (Traditional)</option>
    <option value="fil-PH">Filipino</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="en-FJ">Fijian</option>
    <option value="en-AU">English Australia</option>
    <option value="en-WS">Samoan</option>
    <option value="en-US">English United States</option>
    <option value="el-GR">Greek</option>
    <option value="es-ES">Spanish</option>
    <option value="et-EE">Estonian</option>
    <option value="fa-IR">Persian</option>
    <option value="fi-FI">Finnish</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">French</option>
    <option value="fr-HT">Haitian</option>
    <option value="af-ZA">Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="ar-SY">Arabic Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="ar-EG">Arabic Egypt</option>
    <option value="da-DK">Danish</option>
    <option value="de-DE">German</option>
    <option value="bg-BG">Bulgarian</option>
    <option value="bn-BD">Bangla</option>
    <option value="mg-MG">Malagasy</option>
    <option value="ms-MY">Malay</option>
    <option value="mt-MT">Maltese</option>
    <option value="ca-ES">Catalan</option>
    <option value="cs-CZ">Czech</option>
    <option value="nl-NL">Dutch</option>
    <option value="nb-NO">Norwegian</option>
    <option value="id-ID">Indonesian</option>
    <option value="it-IT">Italian</option>
    <option value="lt-LT">Lithuanian</option>
    <option value="lv-LV">Latvian</option>
    <option value="ja-JP">Japanese</option>
    <option value="ur-PK">Urdu</option>
    <option value="uk-UA">Ukrainian</option>
    <option value="hi-IN">Hindi</option>
    <option value="he-IL">Hebrew</option>
    <option value="hu-HU">Hungarian</option>
    <option value="hr-HR">Croatian</option>
    <option value="ko-KR">Korean</option>
    <option value="vi-VN">Vietnamese</option>
    <option value="tr-TR">Turkish</option>
    <option value="ta-IN">Tamil</option>
    <option value="th-TH">Thai</option>
    <option value="to-TO">Tongan</option>
    <option value="ru-RU">Russian</option>
    <option value="ro-RO">Romanian</option>
    <option value="pt-BR">Portuguese</option>
    <option value="pl-PL">Polish</option>
    <option value="sv-SE">Swedish</option>
    <option value="sw-KE">Kiswahili</option>
    <option value="sl-SI">Slovenian</option>
    <option value="sk-SK">Slovak</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<p id="result" />
  <script>
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  const language = document.getElementById("language").value;
  const url = `https://api.videoindexer.ai/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index?language=${language}&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=...`;
  //url.searchParams.set("language",language);
  console.log(url); // change to a fetch or similar
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = url
})
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not a bad suggestion, @kdvinmk, though at least in Firefox and Chrome it didn't matter. Works for me in both.

Comment: I tried the same code locally, and It seems to work perfectly for me, so i thought the only place it was off was the placement of the tags.

Comment: @Kdvinmk sorry when you say you tried it locally, I am running it from file:///C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/language.html is that okay?

Comment: You might get in trouble that way - from a local file. I would not be surprised if you did. Mine is up on a server, for example. I should say that it works for me also that way - I dragged it onto a browser window. Worked fine. Exactly as above.

Comment: As long as you are connected to the internet you must be fine. What response are you expecting exactly ? the modified url which has the value of the selected option in place of the language=..., right?

Comment: @Kdvinmk that's right I am expecting a URL which has the value of selected option. But when I click 'Submit" I don't see anything happening what so ever. So I am wondering If am running it wrong locally.

Comment: Can you upload your source files somewhere, and let us see it. We can be of better help.

Comment: @Kdvinmk I have uploaded a snapshot of it looks on my end(above). When I click "Submit", I get no response at all.

Comment: Where do you want the result ? On the console ? or below the form ?

Comment: @Kdvinmk below the form

Comment: @Peter I have updated my Answer, Pls take a look at that. Instead of url.searchParams.set, I just used back-ticks for the string and concatenated the constant inside the string, you can do it your way also, but i found this easier

Comment: @Kdvinmk that makes sense, and it's working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The URL interface is documented here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

That object created by new URL(...) doesn't look so good in console.log.
Try this instead.

```js
            console.log(url.href);
            console.log(typeof url);
```

This is what I see when I do console.log(url) (an object) -
URL { href: "https://api.videoindexer.ai/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index?language=en-GB&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=...", origin: "https://api.videoindexer.ai", protocol: "https:", username: "", password: "", host: "api.videoindexer.ai", hostname: "api.videoindexer.ai", port: "", pathname: "/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index", search: "?language=en-GB&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=..." }

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <select name="language" id="language">
        <option value="en-GB">Please select language (Default en-GB</option>
        <option value="sr-Cyrl-RS">Serbian (Cyrillic)</option>
        <option value="sr-Latn-RS">Serbian (Latin)</option>
        <option value="bs-Latn">Bosnian</option>
        <option value="zh-Hans">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
        <option value="zh-Hant">Chinese (Traditional)</option>
        <option value="fil-PH">Filipino</option>
        <option value="en-GB">English United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="en-FJ">Fijian</option>
        <option value="en-AU">English Australia</option>
        <option value="en-WS">Samoan</option>
        <option value="en-US">English United States</option>
        <option value="el-GR">Greek</option>
        <option value="es-ES">Spanish</option>
        <option value="et-EE">Estonian</option>
        <option value="fa-IR">Persian</option>
        <option value="fi-FI">Finnish</option>
        <option value="fr-FR">French</option>
        <option value="fr-HT">Haitian</option>
        <option value="af-ZA">Afrikaans</option>
        <option value="ar-SY">Arabic Syrian Arab Republic</option>
        <option value="ar-EG">Arabic Egypt</option>
        <option value="da-DK">Danish</option>
        <option value="de-DE">German</option>
        <option value="bg-BG">Bulgarian</option>
        <option value="bn-BD">Bangla</option>
        <option value="mg-MG">Malagasy</option>
        <option value="ms-MY">Malay</option>
        <option value="mt-MT">Maltese</option>
        <option value="ca-ES">Catalan</option>
        <option value="cs-CZ">Czech</option>
        <option value="nl-NL">Dutch</option>
        <option value="nb-NO">Norwegian</option>
        <option value="id-ID">Indonesian</option>
        <option value="it-IT">Italian</option>
        <option value="lt-LT">Lithuanian</option>
        <option value="lv-LV">Latvian</option>
        <option value="ja-JP">Japanese</option>
        <option value="ur-PK">Urdu</option>
        <option value="uk-UA">Ukrainian</option>
        <option value="hi-IN">Hindi</option>
        <option value="he-IL">Hebrew</option>
        <option value="hu-HU">Hungarian</option>
        <option value="hr-HR">Croatian</option>
        <option value="ko-KR">Korean</option>
        <option value="vi-VN">Vietnamese</option>
        <option value="tr-TR">Turkish</option>
        <option value="ta-IN">Tamil</option>
        <option value="th-TH">Thai</option>
        <option value="to-TO">Tongan</option>
        <option value="ru-RU">Russian</option>
        <option value="ro-RO">Romanian</option>
        <option value="pt-BR">Portuguese</option>
        <option value="pl-PL">Polish</option>
        <option value="sv-SE">Swedish</option>
        <option value="sw-KE">Kiswahili</option>
        <option value="sl-SI">Slovenian</option>
        <option value="sk-SK">Slovak</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
    <script>
        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
            const url = new URL("https://api.videoindexer.ai/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index?language=...&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=...");
            const language = document.getElementById("language").value;
            url.searchParams.set("language",language);
            console.log(url); // change to a fetch or similar
            // console.log(url.href);
            // console.log(typeof url);
        })
    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should probably say that I _do_ get a response when I use your code and click submit. I'm not sure why you don't. I'll see about putting that in the answer.

Comment: @Yishmerary oh really? When I click submit, I don't get any response at all. Could you please share how you had formatted the HTML file? Thank you.

Comment: @Peter Well, I could, but it wouldn't help much, since all I did was copy and paste your code into a new file and uploaded it to a server. Are you seeing anything at all in the console? Hate to ask the obvious, but you are looking at the console, yes?

Comment: @Yishmerary, if you don't mind, I would like to see the html file you created. Even if it's the same

Comment: OK, there you go.